# why UChar* is not working  with this ICU conversion?

Tags: c++, utf-8, icu

When converting from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-6 this code didn't work:

```
UnicodeString ustr = UnicodeString::fromUTF8(StringPiece(input));

const UChar* source = ustr.getBuffer();

char target[1000];
UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
UConverter *conv;
int32_t     len;

// set up the converter
conv = ucnv_open("iso-8859-6", &status);
assert(U_SUCCESS(status));

// convert 
len = ucnv_fromUChars(conv, target, 100, source, -1, &status);
assert(U_SUCCESS(status));

// close the converter
ucnv_close(conv);

string s(target);
return s;
```

images: ([1](http://www.4shared.com/photo/HtfUz_JT/untitled.html),[2](http://www.4shared.com/photo/EfVx2v-u/untitled2.html))

**However when replacing UChar* with a hard-coded UChar[] it works well!!**
image : ([3](http://www.4shared.com/photo/r0TGOKqb/untitled3.html))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're taking the difficult approach. How about this:

```
static char const* const cp = "iso-8859-6";
UnicodeString ustr = UnicodeString::fromUTF8(StringPiece(input));
std::vector<char> buf(ustr.length() + 1);
std::vector<char>::size_type len = ustr.extract(0, ustr.length(), &buf[0], buf.size(), cp);
if (len >= buf.size())
{
    buf.resize(len + 1);
    len = ustr.extract(0, ustr.length(), &buf[0], buf.size(), cp);
}
std::string ret;
if (len)
    ret.assign(buf.begin(), buf.begin() + len));
return ret;
```

Comment: unfortunately the same result

Comment: @ildjarn: the result is a string of rubbish characters (that seems to mean that the conversion was not successful)

Comment: @Abdelwahed : And your input data is..?

Comment: @ildjarn: the input is an Arabic utf-8 string. I can see, in debugging, that ustr contained the Arabic letters correctly.But after conversion the output is not understandable.

Comment: @Abdelwahed : Post the *actual string* here please, so others may test/debug.

Comment: @ildjarn: input contains "السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته" in utf-8 encoded format (read from file by Java and passed to C++ via JNI)

Comment: replacing the (UChar*) with (UChar source[]) and choosing hard coded characters yields a correct result

Comment: @Abdelwahed : I just tested this code -- its output is identical to using the WinAPI to do the encoding translation, so I believe you're just having an issue with displaying the results. How are you attempting to display/use the output?

Comment: @ildjarn here are my test (http://www.4shared.com/photo/EfVx2v-u/untitled2.html) (http://www.4shared.com/photo/HtfUz_JT/untitled.html)

Comment: @Abdelwahed : That looks correct to me. Visual Studio has no idea what encoding/codepage the data is in, so it tries to interpret it as ASCII, but that doesn't mean the data's wrong, only that VS doesn't know how to display it. Check the actual byte values of the data in the memory window to verify correctness, they should be as follows: `C7 E4 D3 E4 C7 E5 20 D9 E4 EA E3 E5 20 E8 D1 CD E5 C9 20 C7 E4 E4 E7 20 E8 C8 D1 E3 C7 CA E7`

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks for your support till now. I use this code to convert utf-8 to ANSI (Arabic Version) "iso-8859-6". VS displays it correctly if it is encoded in this ANSI version. I tried it before. Moreover I will work on the ret[i] directly. If it is not the right character (like the case here) then i won't manipulate it.

Comment: @ildjarn: here is the result with the hard-coded Uchar[] (http://www.4shared.com/photo/r0TGOKqb/untitled3.html)

Comment: @Abdelwahed : You're completely missing the point. Stop expecting Visual Studio to display the data correctly as a string, and verify the underlying data in the [memory window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx).

Comment: @ildjarn: tell me how can I run this code [ 
static const char BEH = '\u0628';
if(ret[0] == BEH){
  ret[0] == ' ';
 }]

Comment: @Abdelwahed - comparing the hard coded UChar characters to what you get using original code, can you verify the UChar codepoints?  It seems like if your code works with the hard coded codepoints, that it's the utf-8 part which isn't working right. Can you give the UChars that you get originally vs hard coded?